# Split out data from a column

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, columns, cut

So at the moment I have some input email addresses and would like to separate the alias and the domain, then copy them to the end of the line. For example, from a line that has `something@test.com:blah:blah`, I would like to have `something@test.com:blah:blah:something:test.com`.

I think I could cut based on the `@` delimiter to output a list of all the aliases and then a list of all the domains, but I do not know how to add these to an existing line one by one. Ideas?

Comment: Have you read the man pages for `cut` and `paste` yet?

Comment: Can I recommend the excellent [Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/index.html)?

Answer (score 0):

here a bit clumsy way to get this thread started

```
% x="something@test.com:blah:blah" 
% first=$(echo $x|cut -d "@" -f 1)
% second=$(echo $x|cut -d "@" -f 2|cut -d ":" -f 1)
% echo "$x:$first:$second" 

something@test.com:blah:blah:something:test.com
```

Comment: Cool thanks for that. I'll do some reading so hopefully bash has a function that allows you to assign a "line" to a variable so I am able to increment it and use this across all emails in the input file.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ echo 'something@test.com:blah:blah' |
    perl -lne '
        @F = split /(\@|\.|:)/, $_;
        print "$_:$F[0]:$F[2].$F[4]."
    ' 
something@test.com:blah:blah:something:test.com.
```